# Failure of Schur's lemma for topological group representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups

Is there an example of $G$, $\rho$ as below?

- $G$ is a locally compact group.
- $\rho$ is an irreducible continuous representation of $G$ on a complex Hilbert space $V$. This means that we have a continuous homomorphism from $G$ to the group of bounded linear operators on $V$ with bounded inverse, such that $G \times V \rightarrow V$ is continuous. And there are no nontrivial closed invariant subspaces.
- Schur's lemma fails for $\rho$.

(Asked first on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3096704/failure-of-schurs-lemma-for-topological-group-representations)

**Added later:** 
For concreteness, I will record below one version of Schur's lemma that I have in mind. (But I'm not too picky about this.)

*Schur's lemma:* Every bounded operator commuting with $\rho(G)$ is a scalar.

Comment: There are several different statements that get referred to as Schur's lemma, what is the version you are referring to?

Comment: Keep in mind that Schur's lemma originated in the setting of *finite dimensjonal* representations, so what Nate points out is highly relevant here.

Comment: Probably the topology on $G$ is irrelevant, because if Schur's lemma (I guess, if the  representation is topologically irreducible then its commutant is reduced to scalars- you probably mean complex Hilbert space) fails for some representation of a topological group $G$, it fails for the same representation with $G$ being endowed with the discrete topology.

Comment: If it's the correct interpretation of the question, then the question is equivalent to: find a non-scalar bounded operator of a (complex) Hilbert space whose centralizer acts irreducibly on the Hilbert space.

Comment: @Nate I expanded the question with a statement of Schur's lemma. (Also, I added that $\rho$ is irreducible.)